# Working out probability

Tags: probability

Need a little help working out the probability something will be picked over the other.

Currently I have 15 things in one group and 3330 in another. Both groups are put together and I pick 7 things of them at random, what would the odds be that 4 out of 7 would be from the group with 3330 members, I understand it will be almost 100% but i am looking for the equation on how to do this so i can do it for others

Is the correct answer :

0.00052316890882 ?

Worked out by = 7 / 3345 = 0.00209267563528

Then 0.00209267563528 / 4 = 0.00052316890882

Thanks

```
--------------
```

Edit

3345 / 7 = 477.8571429

15 / 4 = 3.75

3330 / 3 = 1110

But 477/3.75 gives me 12742.86% chance of picking all 4 numbers from the 15 group which doesnt seem right ?

Comment: Edited to include what i think is the answer

Comment: The probability that $7/7$ are from $3300$ would be nearly $100$%, but not the probability that $4/7$ are from $3300$.

Comment: $3330 \choose 4$ is the number of [Combinations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) of $4$ items out of a collection of $3330$ where you don't care about the order and the items must be distinct.  It is numerically $\frac {3330!}{4!(3330-4)!}$

Answer (score 1):

The probability of getting $4$ out of $7$ from the $3330$ group is given by
$$\frac{{3330\choose 4}{15\choose 3}}{3345\choose 7}=2.519\times 10^{-6}\; \blacksquare$$

---

NB: the probability of getting all $7$ out of $7$ from the $3330$ group is 
$$\frac{{3330\choose 7}{15\choose 0}}{3345\choose 7}=0.9690$$
which is close to $1$ as would be expected.

Answer (score 0):

There are a total of $3345$ objects.  The number of ways to select $7$ is $3345 \choose 7$.  The number of ways to select exactly $4$ of the $15$ and $3$ of the $3330$ is ${15 \choose 3}{3330 \choose 4}$. [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%2815%20choose%203%29%283330%20choose%204%29%2F%283345%20choose%207%29) says this is about $2.5\cdot 10^{-6}$  If you allow $5,6,7$ you will have to add that in.  Then it will become almost $100\%$ as you say.  The easiest way is to compute the chance you get exactly $3$ out of $3330$ and subtract from $100\%$.  This ignores the chance you get $0,1,2$, but those are smaller yet.  [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%2815%20choose%204%29%283330%20choose%203%29%2F%283345%20choose%207%29) gives this as $9 \cdot 10^{-9}$, so you have $999,999,991$ chances in a billion of getting at least $4$ from the $3330$

Comment: Thanks for the help, i have updated my question with the results but they seem to be really out, is this right ?

Comment: The question specifies $4$ from $3330$, not $15$.